# What is the correct syntax for using StringFormat with single binding?

Tags: xaml, binding

I can get MultiBinding to work with StringFormat:

```
<TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1} (hired on {2:MMM dd, yyyy})">
        <Binding Path="FirstName"/>
        <Binding Path="LastName"/>
        <Binding Path="HireDate"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.Text>
```

**But what is the correct syntax for single binding?** The following doesn't work (although it seems to be the same syntax as [this example](http://dotnet.org.za/rudi/archive/2008/05/16/using-binding-stringformat.aspx)):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=HiredDate, StringFormat='{MMM dd, yyyy}'}"/>
```

## ANSWER:

Thanks Matt, what I needed was a combination of your two answers, this works great:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=HiredDate, 
    StringFormat='Hired on {0:MMM dd, yyyy}'}"/>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to leave the curly braces out of the format string in your example, because you're not using them as a placeholder (like you'd use "{0}" in String.Format()).

So:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=HiredDate, StringFormat='MMM dd, yyyy'}"/>
```

If you want to reference the placeholder value somewhere inside the string, you can do so by escaping the curly braces with a backslash:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=HiredDate, StringFormat='Hired on \{0\}'}"/>
```

Comment: You don't think you need the backslashes on your second example, it works without them, or are they there for some other reason.

Comment: Strange. I've had compilation errors in the past when I've omitted the backslashes. Glad it works for you though!

Comment: I've found that if the string starts  with the brace like '{0} Some Text' then you need to escape the braces. If any other character (like a space) comes first, you don't need to escape them.